# How was the difference of the Fransén–Robinson constant and Euler's number found?

Tags: improper-integrals, gamma-function, transcendental-numbers, constants

I recently ran across the following integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}dx
$$

Which I learned is equal to [the Fransén-Robinson constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frans%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Robinson_constant). On the linked wikipedia page for the Fransén-Robinson constant, it states that the difference between Fransén-Robinson constant and Euler's number can be expressed by this:

$$
F = e + \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\pi^2+\ln^2(x)}dx
$$

Where on earth did the difference come from? How do we know this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a consequence of the $\Gamma$ reflection formula:
$$ \Gamma(z)\,\Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)} \tag{1} $$
and the Cantarini's trick (aka the Laplace transform of the sine function):
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} \sin(a t)\,e^{-bt} = \frac{a}{a^2+b^2}\tag{2} $$
from which:

$$ \frac{1}{\pi^2+\log^2(x)} = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi} x^{-t}\,dt \qquad \left(\log(x)>0\right)\\\frac{1}{\pi^2+\log^2(x)} = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi} x^{t}\,dt \qquad \left(\log(x)<0\right)\tag{3}$$
so $ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\pi^2+\log^2(x)}\,dx$ is related with:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi}\,\Gamma(1-t)\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{\Gamma(t)}\tag{4}$$

Comment: Your answer is brilliant, but I have encountered some difficulties while trying to understand the overall process. I have posted an answer that shows where I do and do not understand.

Comment: How do you get rid of $\Gamma(1-x)$ using Cantarini’s trick if you cannot expand using the usual integral representation of $\Gamma(x)$ as it is valid only for $\text{Re}(x)>0$?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the process I found:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma(x)} dx = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(1-x)}{\pi} \sin{(\pi x)} dx = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} t^{-x} dt dx$$
$$ = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{\pi} \int_0^1 e^{-t} t^{-x} dt dx + \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{\pi} \int_1^\infty e^{-t} t^{-x} dt dx \equiv \mathcal{I}_1 + \mathcal{I}_2$$
We'll start evaluating the easiest one, $\mathcal{I}_2$:
$$\mathcal{I}_2 = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} t^{-x} dt dx = \int_1^\infty \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{\pi} e^{-t} e^{-x \log{t}} dx dt = \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{{\pi}^2 + \log^2(t)} dt$$
Which constitutes a consistent part of the result. To obtain the rest, we shall be a bit more careful when exchanging integral signs.
$$\mathcal{I}_1 = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{\pi} \int_0^1 e^{-t} t^{-x} dt dx = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{\pi} \int_0^1 t^{k-x} dt dx $$
Thanks to the size of $t$, the sum converges and so do the integrals by themselves, we can go on interchanging and solving:
$$= \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{\pi (k-x+1)} dx = \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \int_{-(k+1)}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1} \sin{(\pi x)}}{-x} dx$$
$$= \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{1}{k!} \int_{-(k+1)}^\infty \frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{x} dx = \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{1}{k!} \int_{-\pi (k+1)}^\infty \frac{\sin{(x)}}{x} dx$$
Now break up the integral and compute the sum:
$$= \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{1}{k!} \left[ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{(x)}}{x} dx + \int_{-\pi (k+1)}^0 \frac{\sin{(x)}}{x} dx \right] = \frac{e}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{1}{k!} \int_0^{\pi (k+1)} \frac{\sin{(x)}}{x} dx $$
$$ = \frac{e}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{1}{k!} \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin{((k+1)x)}}{x} dx = \frac{e}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi} \mathcal{Im} \left[ \int_0^{\pi} \frac{e^{ix}}{x} e^{e^{ix}} dx \right]$$
(the sum $\sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{\sin{(kx)}}{k!}$ can be easily evaluated by noticing $\sin{x} = \mathcal{Im} [e^{ix}]$ and using the definition of the exponential)
$$ =  \frac{e}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi} \mathcal{Im} \left[ \int_0^{\pi i} \frac{e^{y}}{y} e^{e^{y}} dy \right] = \frac{e}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} \mathcal{Im} \left[ \int_{-1}^1 \frac{e^{x}}{\log{x}} dx \right] = \frac{e}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} \mathcal{Im} \left[ \int_{-1}^1 \frac{e^{x}}{\ln{|x|} + i\arg{x}} dx \right]$$
We'll evaluate the argument of a pure negative number as $\pi i$, and take the limit as the argument of the pure real positive part goes to zero:
$$ = \frac{e}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-1}^0 \mathcal{Im} \left[ 
 \frac{e^{x}}{\ln{(-x)} + i\pi} \right] dx + \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{e^{x}\arg{x}}{\ln^2{x} + i\arg^2{x}} dx$$
$$ = \frac{e}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{\pi e^{-x}}{\ln^2{x} + \pi^2} dx + 
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{h e^{x}}{\ln^2{x} + h^2} dx$$
The limit will be solved by noting that the integrated function vanishes (for $h$ small enough) everywhere except a neighborhood of 1, hence the logarithm's and exponential's local behaviours predominate:
$$ = \frac{e}{2} + \int_0^1 \frac{e^{-x}}{\ln^2{x} + \pi^2} dx + \frac{1}{\pi} \lim_{h\to 0} \int_{\mathcal{f}{(h)} \lt 1-h}^1 \frac{h e}{(1-x)^2 + h^2} dx = \frac{e}{2} + \int_0^1 \frac{e^{-x}}{\ln^2{x} + \pi^2} dx + \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{e \pi}{2}$$
$$= e + \int_0^1 \frac{e^{-x}}{\ln^2{x} + \pi^2} dx$$
Together with the first integral:
$$\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{I}_1 + \mathcal{I}_2 = e + \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\ln^2{x} + \pi^2} dx$$

Comment: That was a magical rollercoaster to follow

Comment: In your first line you use $\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx$, but this formula is true only for $\mathrm{Re}(z)>0$, while you use it for $z=1-x \in (-\infty,1)$. Is this valid?

Answer (score 0):

According to $(1)$
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} = \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi}\Gamma(1-z)\tag{1}$$
And this naturally leads to $(4)$
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi}\,\Gamma(1-t)\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{\Gamma(t)}\tag{4}$$
According to $(3)$, when $\ln(x)>0$
$$\frac{1}{\pi^2+\ln^2(x)} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi}x^{-t}dt\tag{3}$$
I don't know if my following work is right or not.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\pi^2+\ln^2(x)}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi}x^{-t}dtdx\tag{a}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\pi^2+\ln^2(x)}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{-t}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi}dtdx\tag{b}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\pi^2+\ln^2(x)}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi}\Gamma(1-t)dt\tag{c} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\Gamma(t)}$$
However,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\Gamma(t)}= e + \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\pi^2+\ln^2(x)}dx $$
Where is the extra $e$?

Comment: I am sorry that I have to post my question as an answer, for it is too long to fit in the comment section.

Comment: You have to adjust your argument according to the cases in which $\log(x)\leq 0$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: I tried to use incomplete Gamma function, but it does not work. Could you provide me another hint? I am not sure how to adjust my answer.

Comment: I encounter the exact same problems with the missing factor e. I've tried evaluating this thign for a few days now, no success :/

Comment: @Flammable Maths: I like the Flammable Maths YouTube video. I am a subscriber.

Comment: Haha :D Thanks Larry! =D Were you able to resolve this weird missing $+e$ problem here by now? This theorem is giving me severe headaches lol

Comment: No, I haven’t been able to. I gave it some initial try but kinda give up by now.