# Detailed explanation of the Γ reflection formula understandable by an AP Calculus student

Tags: gamma-function, proof-explanation, weierstrass-factorization

In [my recent question about the Fransén-Robinson constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1802176/277362), an answer was given using the Gamma reflection formula. However, as an AP Calculus student, I didn't quite understand how the reflection formula worked. After two days of research, I have only found explanations for the Gamma reflection formula in terms of Weierstrass products, which I don't begin to understand.

Is there a proof for the Gamma reflection formula by which I can understand, or at least begin to understand, how this formula works?

Comment: Lebedev, Special functions, section 1.2 uses a double-integral approach:

$$\Gamma(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}\, d t \qquad (\Re z > 0)$$

$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}s^{-z}t^{z-1}e^{-(s+t)}\,ds\, dt \qquad (0<\Re z <1)$$

The double-integral can be evaluated as $\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}$. The he uses
continuation to extend the formula to all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ without the
negative integers.

Comment: @gammatester Can you add this as an answer? :P

Comment: I could. But it will be just a quote from Lebedev. Is this OK?

Comment: @gammatester As long as you link the source, it should be. :P I suppose that I'd have to cite the source, though. :\

Comment: I'm not sure if you know how to do contour integration, but here's a link for a proof using that https://highvoltagemath.wixsite.com/highvoltagemath/euler-s-reflection-formula-take-1

Comment: @Highvoltagemath: Wouldn't it be conceptually simpler to first rewrite $$\int_0^\infty \frac {v^{z-1}} {1+v} \, dv  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {e^{zw}} {1 + e^w} \, dw$$ and only then pass to the complex plane? The map $w \mapsto v = e^w$ is the universal cover of the punctured plane $\mathbb C - \{ 0 \}$. In the universal cover, there are no branch cuts to talk about.

Comment: @pyron: There is a link included in the page I sent with my comment that brings you to this page https://highvoltagemath.wixsite.com/highvoltagemath/euler-s-reflection-formula-take-2. It's goes over the derivation of Euler's reflection formula without branch cuts.Thanks for bringing it up though!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/714482/321264

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Note:** This is a description from N.N. Lebedev, Special Functions and Their
Applications, Dover, New York, 1972, it is not my work but it can be used as
starting point.

Lebedev uses in his section 1.2 (*Some Relations Satisfied by the Gamma
Function*) a double-integral approach. From the well-known integral formula

$$\Gamma(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}\, d t \qquad (\Re z > 0)$$

temporarily assume $ 0 < \Re z < 1,\,$  use the formula for $1-z\,$ and get

$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}s^{-z}t^{z-1}e^{-(s+t)}\,ds\, dt \qquad (0<\Re z <1)$$

With the new variables $u = s + t, v = t/s$ this gives
$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{v^{z-1}}{1+v}e^{-u}\,du\, dv  = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{v^{z-1}}{1+v} dv = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}$$

For the last step he refers to Titchmarsh. Then he uses continuation to extend
the formula to all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ without the integers.

Comment: While multivariable calc isn't in the AP Calculus syllabus, this _is_ something that I personally understand and that my fellow students will understand. \o/

Comment: How do you do the variable change between the dsdt and the dudv? I can figure out the inside of the integral, but can't understand how you got from dsdt to dudv.

Comment: Maybe this isn't relevant anymore, but with $u=s+t$ and $v=\dfrac ts$, and thus $s=\dfrac{uv}{v+1}$ and $t=\dfrac u{v+1}$, the Jacobian is (in absolute value) $\dfrac u{(v+1)^2}$, so the integral becomes $$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty t^{-1}\left(\frac ts\right)^ze^{-(s+t)}\,\mathrm ds\,\mathrm dt=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{v+1}uv^{z-1}e^{-v}\frac u{(v+1)^2}\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv$$ $$=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{v^{z-1}}{v+1}e^{-u}\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv$$ But how do we arrive at the limits of integration?

Comment: @gammatester How do you find the general formula of the last Integral? I cannot find where "Titchmarsh" is.

Comment: @user170231: You can find the second set of limits by looking at the how the new variables are bounded. I have a good example of this through the Gaussian integral here: https://highvoltagemath.wixsite.com/highvoltagemath/the-gaussian-integral-redo. I hope this helps, otherwise tell me and I will try it with the integrals in question.

Comment: @highvoltagemath It's been a minute since I posted that comment, but I think my question boiled down to, why is $v\in[0,\infty)$? Both $s,t$ are in $[0,\infty)$, so naturally $u=s+t$ is too. But I wasn't clear on why $v=\frac ts$ also belongs to this interval. Right now, looking at $s,t$ in terms of $u,v$, it's pretty clear why.