# evaluate the improper integral of $\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{1+x}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{x+1}dx$$

If I am using complex analysis is $f(x)=x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ my function? And there are no zeroes or poles on $(0,\infty)$ since $x=-1 \not \in (0,\infty)$ is the only point of interest. Any hints greatly appreciated. I can write the integrand as

$$\frac{1}{x^{4/3}+x^{1/3}}$$
how do I integrate this??

Comment: This is completely different. Now it converges.

Comment: @J.G. the numerator was $x^{-1/3}$ not positive. does this change it?

Comment: @user how do I go about proving this? so I use Cauchy's formula ? Or brut force?

Comment: Now it behaves as $x^{-4/3}$. Don't you see?

Comment: could you elaborate just a bit more , sorry :/

Comment: is it because the $x^{1/3}$ term sort of "dies off"

Comment: @user How do I integrate it from this step $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^{4/3}+x^{1/3}}dx$

Comment: Probably you know that you should apply complex analysis. Otherwise you would not mention it in the question, would you?

Comment: @user Cauchys formula?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{z-1}}{x+1} dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163359/what-is-int-0-infty-fracxz-1x1-dx) (specifically [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3633837))

Comment: @metamorphy that one's slightly different, I got this one answered using substitutions!! thanks though! :) cheers!!!

Comment: But this answer does not use complex analysis which you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{x+1}dx\,\,\,\,\stackrel{x=u^3}{=}\,\,\,\,\int_0^\infty \frac{3u}{u^3+1}du\,\,\,\,\stackrel{v=\frac 1 u}{=}\,\,\,\,\int_0^\infty \frac{3}{v^3+1}dv$$
Thus, summing the last 2 expressions,
$$\begin{split}
2\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{x+1}dx&=3\int_0^\infty \frac{v+1}{v^3+1}dv\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{3}{1-v+v^2}dv\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{4}{1+\frac 4 3\left(v-\frac 1 2\right)^2}dv\\
&= \left[2\sqrt{3}\arctan \left(\frac{2v-1}{\sqrt 3}\right)\right]_0^{+\infty}\\
&=2\sqrt{3}\left(\frac\pi 2+\frac \pi 6\right)\\
&=\frac{4\pi}{\sqrt 3}
\end{split}$$

Thus the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{x+1}dx = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{4 \pi}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: why are you summing the last two expressions? and where did the $2$ come from ?

Comment: also, a bit confused on the $v$ substitution.

Comment: So we found two alternate expressions for the same integral (that's what the first line is about). The next step is to say that twice the original integral is the sum of those two expressions.

Comment: so you rewrote the integral as two distinct integrals and then shouldn't the answer be half of what you have then? So you had it as two integrals, so you wrote twice the integral as the sum of the two "version" of the original integral?

Comment: Also, could you elaborate on how you did the $v$ substitution, I don't see how the $u$ vanishes on top but the denominator stays the same

Comment: Yes, twice the original integral is equal to $\frac {4\pi}{\sqrt 3}$, so the original integral itself is equal to half of that, i.e. $\frac {2\pi}{\sqrt 3}$.

Comment: For the $v$ substitution, I recommend you write it down on paper: it's equal to $\int_0^\infty \frac{3v^{-1}}{v^{-3}+1}\frac{dv}{v^2}=\int_0^\infty \frac{3}{v^3+1}dv$.

Comment: I tried writing t down, got messy, ahh I see thanks !!!

Comment: I keep getting $du=-\frac{1}{v^2} dv$ where did your negative go? sorry for bothering.

Comment: where did the negative go?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133786/discussion-between-stefan-lafon-and-hossien-sahebjame).

Answer (score 0):

This should be a duplicate, but I can't find where this, or a similar more general integral, is evaluated by the desired methods, so let me give a hint that's unfortunately too long for a comment. For small $\epsilon>0$ and large $R>1$, let $\gamma$ be the contour that moves in a line segment from $i\epsilon$ to $R+i\epsilon$, in a near circle to $R-i\epsilon$, in a line segment from $R-i\epsilon$ to $-i\epsilon$, and in a semicircle from $-i\epsilon$ to $i\epsilon$. By the residue theorem,$$\oint_\gamma\frac{\exp(-\frac13\ln z)dz}{1+z}=2\pi i\left.\exp\left(-\frac13\ln z\right)\right|_{z=-1}$$(I leave it to you to work out which branch of the complex logarithm should be used here). Now show the contribution of the semicircle (near-circle) vanishes as $\epsilon\to0^+$ ($R\to\infty$). The rest is$$\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)\right)\int_0^\infty\frac{\exp(-\frac13\ln x)}{1+x}dx,$$because rotating through $2\pi$ radians to get to the second line segment, thereby multiplying $z$ by $e^{2\pi i}=1$ (so the integrand's denominator is unchanged), rescales the integrand. (The $-$ sign is beause we run leftward on the second line segment.)

If this contour shape is unfamiliar, note this is similar to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=2\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ for even $f$. (The much more famous infinite semicircular contour can be thought of in similar terms, if you go from $0$ to $Re^{i0}$ to $Re^{i\pi}$ to $0$.)

Comment: are we using the principle branch of the logarithm? as $z=-1$ we cannot have in the log. By principle brand I mean putting out the negative real axis, so $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}^{\leq 0}$

Comment: @HossienSahebjame If we should take $\ln(-1)=\pi i$, or $\ln(-1)=3\pi i$, or whatever, you can work out a value for your original integral. Can you see which branch makes the answer real? Can you see _another_ reason to accept it? (It's related to the rotating-round-the-circle argument later in my answer.)

Comment: So its the branch excluding the positive reals ?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame I'm not sure what you mean by that. A branch choice in this case means deciding which integer $n$ in $\ln(-1)=\pi i+2n\pi i$ suits here.

Comment: so an $n$ that lands us on the real axis then?

Comment: is it $n=0$? I just competed it out

Answer (score 0):

Well, we are trying to solve the following improper integral:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right):=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\text{n}}{x+\alpha}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Using the 'evaluating integrals over the positive real axis' [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) of the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform), we can write:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=\int_0^\infty\mathscr{L}_x\left[x^\text{n}\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}\cdot\mathscr{L}_x^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{x+\alpha}\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}\space\text{d}\sigma\tag2$$

Using the [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms) of selected Laplace transforms, we can see:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=\Gamma\left(1+\text{n}\right)\int_0^\infty\frac{\exp\left(-\alpha\sigma\right)}{\sigma^{1+\text{n}}}\space\text{d}\sigma\tag3$$

Using the sum [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition) of the $\exp$ function, we can write:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=\Gamma\left(1+\text{n}\right)\lim_{\text{m}\space\to\space\infty}\sum_{\text{k}\space\ge\space0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}\alpha^\text{k}}{\text{k}!}\int_0^\text{m}\sigma^{\text{k}-\text{n}-1}\space\text{d}\sigma\tag4$$

So, we get:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=\Gamma\left(1+\text{n}\right)\lim_{\text{m}\space\to\space\infty}\sum_{\text{k}\space\ge\space0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}\alpha^\text{k}}{\text{k}!}\cdot\frac{\text{m}^{\text{k}-\text{n}}}{\text{k}-\text{n}}\tag5$$

---

Now, when $\text{n}=-\frac{1}{3}$ and $\alpha=1$ we get:

$$\mathcal{I}_{-\frac{1}{3}}\left(1\right)=\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\lim_{\text{m}\space\to\space\infty}\sum_{\text{k}\space\ge\space0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}}{\text{k}!}\cdot\frac{\text{m}^{\text{k}+\frac{1}{3}}}{\text{k}+\frac{1}{3}}=\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\tag6$$