# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x+1)(\pi^2+\ln(x)^2)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I've been given this integral, and I have no idea how to evaluate it. It has a really nice answer of $\frac{1}{2}$ but I have no idea. I tried converting it into a series. I tried differentiating under the integral. I can't find a way of using complex numbers. The only thing I can think of is complex analysis which I don't know. Is there a way to solve it without complex analysis? If not, I wouldn't mind that as a solution.

Here's the integral:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x+1)(\pi^2+\ln(x)^2)}dx$$

Comment: Substitute $x=\frac1y$ and add what you get with the initial integral, then simplify and let $\ln x =t$

Comment: I was thinking of substituting $u = \ln(x)$, but Zacky might be onto something.

Comment: *Mathematica* yields $1/2$.

Comment: Reminds me of the omega integral [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OmegaConstant.html) or the fransen constant minus e [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802176/how-was-the-difference-of-the-fransén-robinson-constant-and-eulers-number-found).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+1)(\pi^2+\log^2 x)}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(x+1)(\pi^2+\log^2 x)}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x(x+1)(\pi^2+\log^2 x)}$$
equals
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x(\pi^2+\log^2 x)}\stackrel{x\mapsto e^t}{=}\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{dt}{\pi^2+t^2}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{\pi^2+u^2}=\left[\frac{\arctan(u/\pi)}{\pi}\right]_{0}^{+\infty}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

An overkill is to exploit the integral representation of [Gregory coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients).

Comment: Nice mentioning Gregory coefficients.  Have any idea about $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)(\pi^2+\log^2 x)}$$
Or possibly a generalization?

Comment: @Zacky: with the same trick as above it reduces to $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(\pi^2+x^2)\cosh(x)}$, which by the Fourier transform equals $\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{e^{\pi s}\cosh(\pi s/2)}$ or $\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{1}{2}$ by letting $s=\frac{2}{\pi}\log u$.

Comment: @Zacky: $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)g(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(\mathscr{F} f)(s)(\mathscr{F}^{-1}g)(s)\,ds.$$ $\frac{1}{\cosh}$ is essentially a fixed point for $\mathscr{F}$ while the Cauchy distribution and the Laplace distribution are conjugated.